# Bluemix unable to view add new user link in bluemix despite having manager role

Tags: ibm-cloud

Trying to add users to the organization space.

Despite being listed as a manager, not able to view any link to invite users.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to manage organization page (not space page), and you should see something like this:

[image]

Then, use Invite a New User link.

Also, in same page, double check your user id has a tick on MANAGER column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.                                                                           Not able to view the to "Invite a New User"  link.                                             However, as per the bluemix documentation, will try to delete the account and get myself invited again to see if the problem gets resolved.

Comment: Ah, you were invited to the Organization? Not the owner? Hummm, not sure if an invited user (although with Manager role) can invite others.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was the invited user. Waiting for my account to be deleted. Will keep my fingers crossed until then :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add users to your own organization (or) an organization are you invited to ?

From Bluemix documentation [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#acctmgmt/index.html#acctmgmt) :

**Users**
The basic role in organizations and spaces. You must be assigned to an organization before you can be granted permissions to the spaces within the organization.
In Bluemix, you can be **either a member or a collaborator** of an organization:

You are a collaborator of an organization if you already have a Bluemix account, and someone else invites you to the organization.
You are a member of an organization if you don't have a Bluemix account, but then someone invites you to the organization and you sign up for Bluemix from the invitation.

**Note:** You cannot invite users to your organization if you are a collaborator of the organization, even if you were assigned as an organization manager. Therefore, if you previously registered for a Bluemix account before you were invited to this organization, you cannot invite users, regardless of your role. See Unable to add users to an organization for information about how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only the owner of the organization can invite any new users.

You can try inviting users from your own organization. (the one which come by default with the name as your Bluemix Id).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it. I can only add users that are already listed users in the drop down and not add new users as I am not the owner.

Comment: Yes right Sam, you can add users into different org spaces which are already part of the organization.